# Formula for a graph that has an asymptote at $y = 1$ where $0\le y<1$ and $0\le x<\infty$

Tags: asymptotics

Is it possible to have a formula that describes the following:
$0\le y<1$ and $0\le x<\infty$
There is an asymptote at $y = 1$; so as $x$ approaches $\infty$, $y$ approaches $1$.

I have played with all manner of $y=1/x^n$ and $x=1/y^n$, square root combinations I can think of and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: How about $ \ y \ = \ \frac{2}{\pi}·\arctan(x) \ \ $ on $ \ [0 \ , \ +\infty) \ \ ? $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\dfrac x{x+1}.\end{array}$$Then the range of $f$ is $[0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I hate how simple that is when I have been banging my head for ages. :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.